# getting FatalErrorException in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run my travel project on AWS server.what I do is copy what I have done on the local computer to AWS server and change the .evn file when I run the project it is saying this error in the log file. (I did try to change permission in the folder but didn't work that also)

```
local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'' in C:\MTASL\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\PermissionRegistrar.php:33
Stack trace:
```

How can i fix this error.

updated 
this the line that it says I did try to change what it says but didn't work

```
  public function registerPermissions(): bool
    {
        try {
            $this->getPermissions()->map(function ($permission) {
                $this->gate->define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
                    return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
                });
            });

            return true;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            if ($this->shouldLogException()) {
                $this->logger->alert(
                    "Could not register permissions because {$exception->getMessage()}".PHP_EOL.
                    $exception->getTraceAsString()
                );
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the answer is right in front of you. now, go to PermissionRegistrar.php line 33 and fix that error.

Comment: Spatie's Laravel Permission package requires PHP 7. Are you running on PHP 7?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.31

Comment: @NuwanIndika - Yeah. So Spatie's Laravel Permissions package does not support PHP 5.6. Either upgrade to a newer version of PHP, or use a different permissions package.

Comment: @ wreigh 
 
update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
 public function registerPermissions(): bool
```

is PHP 7 syntax. Remove ": bool" to have it work on older PHPs.

But chances are that the whole module requires a newer version of PHP than the one you have. The real solution is upgrade your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your code at the line in question. The error tells you what the problem is. My guess without having seen anything is that the line ends in a `:` instead of a `;`